# i tried to develop currency converter application in android. i get error in the ArrayAdapter,

Tags: android

it shows the error in following line

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
this, R.array.name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
val = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value);
```

the error msg is "array cannot be resolved or is not a field".

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public int to;
public int from;
public String [] val;
public String s;
public Handler handler;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
this, R.array.name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
val = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value);
s1.setAdapter(adapter);
s2.setAdapter(adapter);
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinOne(1));
s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new spinOne(2));
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
if(from == to)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", 4000).show();
}
else
{
try {
s = getJson("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public /yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22"+val[from]+val[to]+"%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=");
JSONObject jObj;
jObj = new JSONObject(s);
String exResult=                                                                                  jObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("rate").getString("Rate"    );
t.setText(exResult);
} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}   

});
TextView credit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
credit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://finance.yahoo.com"));
startActivity(i);
}

});
}
public String getJson(String url)throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String con;
while ((con = reader.readLine()) != null) {
build.append(con);
}
return build.toString();
}
private class spinOne implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
int ide;
spinOne(int i)
{
ide =i;
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int index, long id) {
if(ide == 1)
from = index;
else if(ide == 2)
to = index;

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}

}
}
```

Comment: What error? Post the logcat file

Comment: @ShreyaS it shows error in **array** in the following lines
    this, R.array.name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);" and val = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value);
it says "array cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: have you declared these arrays in xml??

Comment: Ok. Is it compile time error? Then hover the mouse on that red line for a second and it will show you error

Comment: @ShreyaS Yes it is. it shows the error as **array cannot be resolved or is not a field**

Comment: Do you have the array file in the resource?...

Comment: You might not have initialized it properly, then

Comment: can you share R.array.name file?

Comment: @TamilarasiSivaraj do u mean R.java file?

Comment: do you have file in the res/values folder that contain resource type array..

Answer (score 0):

In res/values/strings u need to declare ur arrays name and value like :

```
<string-array name="name">
    <item>name 1</item>
     <!-- Put the values u required in the array -->
    <item>name 2</item>
</string-array>

 <string-array name="value">
    <item>value1</item>
     <!-- Put the values u required in the array -->
    <item>value2</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: where can i add AsyncTask in my code? can anyone tell in which line i have to add?

Comment: you can call getJson( String Url) in Asynctask doingBackgroung() of asynctask and then in ur activity where u were calling getJson(url) , execute asynctask

Comment: i tried as u suggested. but it shows error in getJson(url) in the mainactivity, it shows error in **getJson** and in **getJson( String Url)** in doInbackground it shows error in 
 **String getJson(String url)throws ClientProtocolException, IOException**